# UIlabel Font Size issue for iPhone 5, 6 , 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 to develop application for all iPhone sizes (5,6, 6plus). I am having problem with UIlabel font size. For iPhone 5 the UIlabel font size is way too big and for iPhone 6 Plus its too small. Have anyone faced the same problem with font size. By the way I am using storyboard and don't wanna set font size programatically with If-else condition. Please suggest best way to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using minimumFontSize from storyboard?

Comment: Show screenshots of each screen, and storyboard as well. what constraints you have for your UILabel ?

Comment: Thanks  Vibha & Umair . I am handling it by creating subclass of UIlabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a problem made to be handled through size classes but you can currently only specify different fonts for iphone landscape,portrait or ipad landscape,portrait etc.If you want to change fonts for one orientation on iphone than you have to do it programmatically.
The best way to do it will be to create a custom UILabel class and in it's awakefromnib method come up with a formula for fonts and assign the font their e.g

```
self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont" size:self.font.pointSize * [currentviewwidth/viewwidthofxib/storyboard]];
```

Comment: If you cannot understand the formula let me know i will explain it more.The currentviewwidth is 320 if you are running in iphone 5s just give here screenwidth and  viewwidthofxib/storyboard is the width of the canvas that you have designed in e.g in storyboard you have taken the canvas size to be iphone 6 plus so the width will be 414

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. The solution you suggested was the first thing came to my mind and I already implemented the same but I was looking for something better. It looks like there is no other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Maybe in future apple will add some more size classes for us to handle this scenario appropriately but currently i don't know a better one than this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to add `launch image` for all device resolution.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, Set MinimumFontSize for that label in storyboard/xib

Comment: Thanks Neha for your answer but Minimum Font size won't help in this case